# How to avoid 400 error in spring mvc when binding as java Bean

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, http-status-code-400

I'm using spring mvc. In the controller, I want to get parameter as java Bean Order.
Order bean has several parameters, one of them is dueDate (java.util.Date).

```
@RequestMapping("/toAddOrder")
public ModelAndView addOrder(Order order, BindingResult bindingResult){
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:toViewOrder");
}

@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(
        WebDataBinder binder) throws ServletException {
   binder.registerCustomEditor(byte[].class,
            new ByteArrayMultipartFileEditor());

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            dateFormat.setLenient(false);
            binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, false));
}
```

Problem is if I not set value for dueDate before submiting form to controller. Then will meet error. **BAD_REQUEST**, because dueDate is null or "".

So, I want to know, how to avoid this problem? 
Solutions I can found are as follows.
1. js check before submit form.
2. not binding as Order, get parameters from **HttpServletRequest request**

Extra questions I found for last 2 solutions.
If Order Bean has too many parameters, so I will need to write long code to get and set value, this may add load for me in future.

Comment: I think it should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118023/how-to-allow-null-date-in-spring-3-mvc/12476932#12476932

Comment: I have solved this problem. But I meet new problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem. Because I'm a new to Spring MVC. I tried several methods.
But I think follow methods may help if you meet the same problems.

add in your controller

```
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder( WebDataBinder binder) throws ServletException {
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            dateFormat.setLenient(false);
            binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, false));
}
```

**But I meet the new questions.**

If I submit form in value "". I always get error.code **typeMismatch**.

I already configed in **message.properties** file

```
#bean level error message
typeMismatch.order.dueDate = order.dueDate format not match "YYYY-MM-DD"

#global type not match message
typeMismatch = data type not match
```

But when I print error message in head of page, I always get code **typeMismatch** but not **typeMismatch.order.dueDate**.

```
<#if error?has_content>
    <#list error.allErrors as item>
       <@spring.message "${item.code?if_exists}"/><br/>
    </#list>
</#if>
```

Anyone knows how to solve this questions?